# How to change orientation to Landscape in a fragment, but read from sensor when back to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I start a fragment from activity, and this is when I want the orientation to change to landascape, but as soon as the app is back to the activity, I want the orientation to be dependent on the sensor. So far, I do it this way in my fragment:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

But when I go back to the activity, the screen is still in landscape, but instead, when I'm back to the activity, I want the the screen orientation to be dependent on the sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually doing in the `fragment` is setting the `orientation` of  the `Activity` containing it. `getActivity()...`. So what you need to do is reset the orientation of the activity once  the fragment is detached from the activity. You can, for example, override the `onDetach()` for your fragment and call the:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

there. Or you could try to override the various methods within your fragment and see which works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is to use this code where you are going back to the activity. Because it will shift orientation to what user had set to its device.

```
yourActivityReference.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
```

if you donot want to use this then you can use

```
yourActivityReference.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two? I found the documentation a bit vague.